# How to count the number of rows in a jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How do I count the number of rows in a jqGrid?

To clarify, there is not much data involved so the grid is pulling all of its data back from the server in a single query, instead of using pagination.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
```

**Update**

Note there are two parameters to determine record count:

> **records**
>
> integer
>
> Readonly property. Gives the number of records returned as a result of a query to the server.

---

> **reccount**
>
> integer
>
> Readonly property. Determines the exact number of rows in the grid. Do not confuse this with `records` parameter. Although in many cases they may be equal, there are cases where they are not. For example, if you define rowNum to be 15, but the request to the server returns 20 records, the records parameter will be 20, but the reccount parameter will be 15 (the grid you will have 15 records and not 20).

Comment: Ah yes, I should've known more about the jqGrid before answering.  Here's a reference: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fi5wo.htm

Comment: Just so you know, the latest docs have been moved to a Wiki: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: JacobM - Thanks, I knew there had to be a better way! Also, now that I actually read this section of the docs :) - you may want to add a description of reccount which does something similar.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#grid").getGridParam("reccount");
```

Readonly property. Returns integer. Determines the **exact number of rows** in the grid. (And not the number of records fetched).

More information [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I have so far. It seems like there should be a better way:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").getDataIDs().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
jQuery("#myGrid tr").length;
```

Actually, you can take that a step further with the optional context parameter.

```
jQuery("tr", "#myGrid").length;
```

Either one will search for every "tr" inside of "#myGrid".  However, from my own testing,  specifying the context parameter is usually faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
```

Comment: The accepted answer was written before the new `.jqGrid` API was developed. I just edited that answer to use your code snippet, since it is now the preferred way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
jQuery("#GridId").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```