# Javascript: unable to compare string with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a value from a div & trying to compare with `if` condition but every-time execute in wrong way, Why ? please help me

example:W.r.t my code i got the `totalcount` value as 2, but again it is going into the if block , it should not go

My code:

```
var totalcount=$("#itemLocationGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');//gives value 2
 Number(totalcount);

 if(totalcount===0);
   {  //every time it executes. why?
    alert("No item locations found to perform this ADD action."); 
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: What do you think `parseInt(0)` does? `parseInt` is to parse a *string* into a *number*. `0` is already a number.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right. Also, you just said it gives 2. Your `if` statement, even if it was only `totalcount == 0` would never hit?

Comment: cant you read the error in console ?

Comment: @RGraham: The OP's question is, why is it going into the block even though the value is 2 and they're testing for 0.

Comment: remove Number(totalcount); cause it will return as int and remove semicoln(;) after if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the semicolon...

```
if(totalcount===parseInt(0)  || totalcount == "0" || totalcount == 0);
// ...here ----------------------------------------------------------^
```

That semicolon terminates the `if` statement; what follows it is a block that is *not* conditional on the `if`. You want to remove it so the block is associated with the `if`.

---

If you want a number in `totalcount` and `jqGrid` returns the value as a string (I don't know that it does, but *if* it does), and in particular you want a whole number ("integer"), here's how you get it:

```
var totalcount = parseInt($("#itemLocationGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records'), 10);
// Parse it -----^ and use a radix (number base) ---------------------------------^^^^
```

Having done that (or if `jqGrid` gives you a string), this is how you compare it:

```
if (totalcount === 0)
{
    // Do something because it's zero
}
```

Using `==` will also work. The difference is that `===` will not coerce types to make things match, `==` will (e.g., `"0" == 0` is true but `"0" === 0` is false).

Comment: I like how we were all distracted by the odd `parseInt` call, but there was a semicolon at the end making it all null and void.

Comment: If `totalcount` can be a string `'0'` then OP can write `if(0 == +totalcount)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If `totalcount` is a string, the OP can also just write `if (0 == totalcount)`, the JavaScript engine will coerce it automatically. Doesn't mean it's a good idea. If you know the number is in a specific number base, it's *almost* always best to tell the engine what number base you expect, esp. with engines that add octal handling and thus misunderstand (and reject) `"08"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the semicolon for if condition. also you do not need using number. totalcount you get is already in integer format as you are getting the record (**[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566772/1719752)**).Code will look something like this.

```
var totalcount=$("#itemLocationGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');//gives value 2
if(totalcount===0)
  {  //every time it executes. why?
   alert("No item locations found to perform this ADD action."); 
   return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

No need of other conditions

```
 if(totalcount===parseInt(0)  || totalcount == "0" ||)
```

Your code:

```
if(totalcount == 0)// also remove ; here
       { 
        alert("No item locations found to perform this ADD action."); 
        return false;
       }
```